# Rust (Newbie): Read and write (mutable) access to the same underlying array from multiple threads for in-memory database?

Tags: rust

I'm considering making Rust my primary development language instead of Go, so I've been reading the docs.

One thing that my work requires a lot of is reading and writing from multiple threads into a custom database that is stored in memory as a single massive array and could be 32GB in size. The database functions are designed to avoid race conditions, and mutexes or atomic primitives are used where necessary.

The Rust doc implies that an array can only be either mutable (writeable) on a single thread, or non-mutable (read only) by many threads, and cannot be writable on one and readable on another simultaneously. How then can an in-memory database be used...? It doesn't make sense!

Do I have this wrong?

Forgive me that I can't give any specific Rust example, because I'm still learning the Rust syntax, and to be honest I need to know the answer to this question before using all my time learning a language I will be unable to use.

Comment: If you want access to an array  of type `T` from multiple threads use a smart reference like `Arc<Mutex<T>>`. This will allow you to access the array in multiple threads for reading and writing.

Comment: @CoronA, so then the whole thing is wrapped in a mutex managed by Rust? Is it going to read-lock the entire database any time any value in the DB is modified? That won't do. I don't want Rust to handle the mutexes for me.

Comment: @CoronA But this `Mutex` will probably act as a global lock on the whole array. I guess the OP needs a thinner grained lock in order to access independent parts of the array simultaneously. Something à la [`chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) but probably with an irregular split pattern.

Comment: Is there an 'unsafe' way of doing this that will just work?

Comment: @Alasdair yes, with `unsafe` you can do whatever you want with pointers, but in this case if the main part of your application (in-memory database management) is `unsafe`, may be Rust won't help that much and C++ would be a better alternative.

Comment: If you truly are insistent on modelling your central database as a single array that multiple threads write to and read from at the same time, Rust will not be the right choice for you. It very much goes against the 'shared memory' school of thought of concurrency.

Comment: There are severable cases, where this kind of concurrency is unavoidable. If this is the case here, my answer is one way to do it.

Comment: *The database functions are designed to avoid race conditions, and mutexes or atomic primitives are used where necessary* So how do you guarantee that one thread doesn't write to one part of the database while another thread is reading from the same part? Whatever you're doing with mutexes and atomics, you can do that in Rust, probably with a judicious application of `unsafe`. Bear in mind most languages have *nothing* like Rust's `&mut T`, which is an *exclusive* reference; C makes do with just `*const T` and `*mut T` which have no validity or exclusivity guarantees at all.

Answer (score 3):

There is an unsafe way to do it, namely using the UnsafeCell, which returns mutable raw pointers to its interior data. These are not tracked by the Borrow-Checker and so you have to make sure the invariants are upheld

```
pub struct UnsafeVec<T> {
    data: UnsafeCell<Vec<T>>
}

impl<T> UnsafeVec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        UnsafeVec { data: UnsafeCell::new(Vec::new()) }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, arg: T) {
        self.data.get_mut().push(arg)
    }

    pub unsafe fn index_mut(&self, index: usize) -> &mut T {
        &mut (*self.data.get())[index]
    }
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for UnsafeVec<T> {}
unsafe impl<T> Send for UnsafeVec<T> {}
```

which allows you to write

```
fn main() {
let mut unsafe_vec = UnsafeVec::<i32>::new();
    unsafe_vec.push(15);
    unsafe {
        *unsafe_vec.index_mut(0) += 1;
    }
}
```

The method index_mut allows to modify the interior vector with an immutable reference.
The Sync and Send traits signal the compiler that the type can be safely shared across threads, which is only true if you prevent possible data races manually!.
Again, this is an unsafe option that requires you to uphold the invariants yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think though that the level of abstraction needed to get it to work makes Rust a bad choice. I'll learn C++ instead.

Comment: This is intentional in rust, since the rust compiler tries to catch all possible errors at compile time. So things the compiler can't check for you are "unsafe". That is not to say you shouldn't do them, but rather that you should take extra care when you do. While rust is frustrating at first due to the many compiler errors, soon you'll realise it's your best friend, since it helps write sound code. C++ is the other way around: everything is allowed and the language assumes you know what you're doing, even when you're wrong. I switched from C++ to rust and it's my favourite language now.